# Starting Netbeans Profiler

Tags: netbeans, profiler

I am trying to profile a Java application in Netbeans and I keep getting the following errors.

...\nbproject\profiler-build-impl.xml:62: Must set JVM to use for profiling in profiler.info.jvm
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Can anyone give me any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think.  I managed to get it to work (more or less) by doing the following:

1. Open NetBeans properties and click the Java tab (for me, NetBeans->Preferences...->Java)
2. There should be a Properties text area.  In it, I added the following (as it gave me new errors with each line):

profile.class=com.piazza.tools.AutotaggingTrainer

profiler.info.jvmargs.agent=-profile-pre-init

profiler.info.jvm=/usr/bin/java

profiler.info.dir=profiling

(The extra blank lines in-between are because stackoverflow kept trying to put them all on one line.  :/ )
It works for me now, kinda, but sometimes hangs for no apparent reason.